# Web-page extracting data from Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

It is possible to grab data from webpage into Chrome extension but is it possible to do the opposite i.e. webpage extracting data from chrome extension.

The scenario is: When we load a new page in a tab, then the chrome extension will be collect data from server and the webpage can collect that data from the plugin when ever required.
In general it is not a good solution, but when multiple webpages uses same data data then instead of all pages interacting with server, only chrome extension will that once and every page gets the data.

It is possible to collect the data from server by extension, but how can the webpage get the data by requesting the extension? May be it is possible in some way.

Note: Discussion is generic for all browsers, but I have just tagged Chrome-extensions because I am trying to start from Chrome.

Comment: Please note: I am able to collect data from server via extension.
But the question is how the page can request extension for that data to modify itself, instead of extension doing it.

Comment: Why not just serve the resources with appropriate cache headers? That benefits every user of the site, not just the ones with the extension installed.

Comment: Its not about users, the webpage developer do not have this data and can only fetch it via extensions.

Comment: What kind of data? JavaScript files? (JSON(P)) responses from a web service? Images?

Comment: Data in JSON format (via web services)

Comment: If this data is through AJAX, the only option is injecting a script which intercepts the requests.

Comment: Finally, I got my answer by my research. It is possible by using "message passing APIs".
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

Comment: Please post your findings in an answer below, preferably with sample code.

Answer (score 3):

Potential solution is by using "Message Passing APIs".

```
// The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
var id = "abcd..";

// Make a simple request:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(id, {openUrlInEditor: url},function(response) {
if (!response.success)
 handleError(url);
});
```

From the extension, you may listen to messages from web pages via the runtime.onMessageExternal or runtime.onConnectExternal APIs, Here is an example:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (sender.url == blacklistedWebsite)
   return;  // don't allow this web page access
if (request.openUrlInEditor)
  openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
});
```

Source: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution here would be to use background scripts to get the required data, then inject JSON objects into the page via chrome.tabs.executeScript...

Comment: The problem is not about injecting the code, which is simple. It is opposite of that: webpage requesting the data from the extension to modify itself.
I have posted the solution above for this. Please accept if you find it useful.